# Resteasy rest responses of quarkus app ignore jackson config quarkus.jackson.write-dates-as-timestamps=true

Tags: jackson, quarkus, resteasy

in the process of migrating a java app to quarkus, we have encountered that resteasy responses which include a java.util.Date object, are being converted to a Date String instead of a long timestamp in milliseconds.

According to the quarkus documentation, this default behavior is normal and can be disabled by putting `quarkus.jackson.write-dates-as-timestamps=true` in the application.properties file, but it seems to be ignored as the result stays a string date instead of a timestamp regardless of this config being set to `true`.
We also tried to set this config property explicitly via an `ObjectMapperCustomizer`, but that didn't work out either.

Quarkus version: 2.9.0

Any ideas how we can force timestamps for any resteasy response?

Affected Code: https://github.com/labsai/EDDI

EDIT:
I have added a resteasy endpoint with a test response containing a date to more easily reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/labsai/EDDI/blob/master/src/main/java/ai/labs/eddi/configs/Test.java

Start app with `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev` (docker needs to be enabled, otherwise you need a mongodb up and running)

Then `GET http://localhost:7070/test` which results in `{"date":"2022-05-16T07:49:13.001Z[UTC]"}`

Comment: Which part of the code you shared is affected?

Comment: Every resteasy endpoint is affected. I have added a simple test resource (see above) in order to easily reproduce the issue.. @geoand

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is because Jackson is **not** being used to serialize JSON.
Instead, JSON-B is handling that task.

quarkus-jsonb is getting included from the following tree:

```
[INFO] ├─ io.quarkiverse.microprofile:quarkus-microprofile-deployment:jar:2.7.2.Final (compile)
[INFO] │  ├─ io.quarkiverse.microprofile:quarkus-microprofile:jar:2.7.2.Final (compile)
[INFO] │  │  ├─ io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jsonb:jar:2.9.0.Final (compile)
[INFO] │  │  │  ├─ io.quarkus:quarkus-jsonb:jar:2.9.0.Final (compile)
```

You can use one of Quarkus' ability to "hide" certain classpath resources.

```
quarkus.class-loading.removed-resources."org.jboss.resteasy\:resteasy-json-binding-provider"=org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/jsonb/JsonBindingProvider.class
```

See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-core_quarkus.class-loading.removed-resources-removed-resources) for more details.

Comment: You are right, that is the problem indeed! Thank you for looking into this! I tried to exclude quarkus-jsonb and resteasy-jsonb, but both resulted in class not found errors. So I assume microprofile needs them. So it seems i would have to exclude the microprofile package all together in order to get jackson being used by resteasy. Do you see any other way of having resteasy use jackson for serialization without having to remove the microprofile package? @geoand

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it results in a ClassNotFoundException: "org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jsonb.JsonBindingProvider" when adding this config. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: What does the stacktrace for that error look like?

Comment: `io.quarkus.restclient.runtime.RestClientRecorder.registerProviders(RestClientRecorder.java:67)` and in another trace `io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit345281060.deploy_0(Unknown Source)`